# Scala - string of algebraic operations

Tags: string, scala

I have a string representing some basic algebraic operations, for example:

```
 "42 * 67 + 4"
```

I would like a function of type

```
 function (operation: String) : Int = {}
```

such that it takes a string of algebraic operations and returns the actual final value, in this case: 2818

I would know how to extract the numbers from such a string but I do not have clear how to extract the mathematical operations such as '+', '-', '*', '/' and actually compute them.

Comment: You can use a [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), though there are many ways to parse and evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to implement the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to do this sort of calculations without any external libraries:

```
def calculate(operation: String): Int = {
  var results: List[Int] = Nil
  var operators: List[String] = Nil

  def precedence(operator: String) = operator match {
    case "+" | "-" => 0
    case "*" | "/" => 1
  }

  def execute(operator: String): Unit = {
    (results, operator) match {
      case (x :: y :: rest, "+") => results = (y + x) :: rest
      case (x :: y :: rest, "-") => results = (y - x) :: rest
      case (x :: y :: rest, "*") => results = (y * x) :: rest
      case (x :: y :: rest, "/") => results = (y / x) :: rest
      case (_, _) => throw new RuntimeException("Not enough arguments")
    }
  }

  for (term <- "[1-9][0-9]*|[-+/*]".r.findAllIn(operation)) {
    util.Try(term.toInt) match {
      case util.Success(number) => results ::= number
      case _ =>
        val (operatorsToExecute, rest) = 
          operators.span(op => precedence(op) >= precedence(term))
        operatorsToExecute foreach execute
        operators = term :: rest
    }
  }
  operators foreach execute

  results match {
    case res :: Nil => res
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Too many arguments")
  }
}
```

This uses integer division:

```
scala> calculate("3 / 2")
res0: Int = 1
```

And has correct precedence of addition and multiplication:

```
scala> calculate("2 + 2 * 2")
res1: Int = 6
```

Support of:

- more kinds of operations,
- parentheses, e.g. `2 * (2 + 2)`,
- floating-point calculations,
- better testing of the formula content (currently it simply ignores all characters except numbers and operators)
- not throwing errors (for example, returning `Try[Int]`, `Option[Int]`, etc. instead of the current behaviour of returning a bare `Int` or throwing an error)

is left as an exercise to the reader.

For more complex things, of course it would be better to use [`scala-parser-combinators`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-parser-combinators/#package) or some third-party parsing library as proposed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

So, @Gábor Bakos posted his joking comment, while I was still composing and testing my joking answer, but I'll post it anyway.

Note: it works. Sometimes. A bit.
Note2: it's a joke!

```
def function(operation: String) = {
  val js = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript")
  js.eval(operation) match { case i: Integer => i.asInstanceOf[Int] }
}

function("42 * 67 + 4")
// => 2818 : Int
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a computer scientists so my sense of humour is different from yours and I don't get your jokes